# Partial derivative with unknown function f(x,y)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I got a task from my lecture, i have tried to do that and this is my solution for the task. I was confused because the function f(x,y), g(r,$\theta$), and h(r,$\theta$) were not defined, so i just can use the value of that functions.

[Click on this link to see my solution]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpxJN.png)

Is it my solution correct?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, it's not correct because it's a common trap instructors set. Hint: the partials of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ are not functions of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi , oh i see. So, to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,\theta)$, i must calculate the value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)* \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} (r,\theta) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y)* \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} (r,\theta)$?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Ok, thanks @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = 2*6 + 4*8 = 44
$$

Here the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ should be evaluated at $(-1,1)$